# wallet encryption

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, encryption

When I created a Wallet in Monero GUI there are three files that are created : wallet,  wallet.address, wallet.keys. How could I read wallet.keys I think it is using some kind of encryption like AES, In addition what data are stored in wallet.keys? I guess for the file wallet are the transactions...

Note: I'm doing a research